# Gcov is not generating *.gcda file

Tags: gcov

I am using `gcov` for analyzing coverage of `.c` file. on compilation it is generation .gcna but on execution it is not generating `gcda` file. 
I already applied `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` flags in my `run.sh` script. And using library `-lgcov -coverage`.

I am running it on arm compiled environment